# Run-time error '3001' after adding MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works fine until I add a comment that spits out the length of something I'm working on (line 3). I can't for the life of me figure out why simply adding a message box crashes the whole thing. The same thing happens if I add another condition to the if statement. What's going on??

```
If rs.Fields(iCols).Name = "Image1" Then
    'MsgBox rs.Fields(iCols).Value
    MsgBox Len(rs.Fields(iCols))
    'Worksheets("Checklist").Range("A117").Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Value
    Set mstream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    mstream.Type = 1         ''adTypeBinary
    mstream.Open
    mstream.Write rs.Fields(iCols).Value
    mstream.SaveToFile "C:\temp\" & "Image1" & ".jpg", 2    ''adSaveCreateOveWrite
    mstream.Close

    Dim myPict As Picture
    Dim PictureLoc As String
    PictureLoc = "C:\Temp\Image1.jpg"

    With Range("A1")
        'Set myPict = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureLoc)
        Set myPict = Worksheets("PI Pics").Pictures.Insert(PictureLoc)
        .RowHeight = 15
        myPict.Top = .Top
        myPict.Left = .Left
        myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        myPict.Width = 200
        myPict.Height = 200
    End With
End If
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with Len here?

Comment: Do you get an error message?  What exactly did you add to the `If` statement?  Remember that VBA doesn't "short-circuit" with and/or: if there are two checks then both get evaluated regardless of the outcome of the first.

Comment: You may want to make sure it's not NULL before checking the length. If it's NULL you will get an error. Try it like this instead: `MsgBox Len("" & rs(iCols))`

Comment: I'm just trying to see if the value of Image1 in the database is longer than a certain number of characters.

Comment: Tim, yes I get the error message. "Run-time error '3001': Arguments are of the wrong type..."

This is what I added to the if. It only seems to care if I use the .Value. If I put .Name in it works fine.
If rs.Fields(iCols).Name = "Image1" And rs.Fields(iCols).Value <> "''" Then

braX, the contents are never null. If there is no image in the db, it sticks '' in (two apostrophes). I tried it like you mentioned, but it still gives the 3001 error.

Comment: I would test debugging by just doing `Msgbox "TEST"` to see if you get any popup or an error so you can narrow down the issue here.

Comment: So you are saying that `rs.Fields(iCols)` is an Image/OleObject field, not a Text field?

Comment: If so, use `LenB` instead of `Len`

Comment: It's a blob field that stores the image in byte form (I think that's how it works). LenB was no luck either. The error doesn't cause a problem so maybe I can just hide the error.

Comment: Perhaps try converting to a string? Len(CStr(....))